# How to combine Multi-index and pivot to create a truth table in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas DataFrame, where column Z can have an unknown number of possible values eg A,B,C,D,E ... :

```
X Y Z
-----
1 1 A
1 1 B
1 1 C
1 2 A
2 1 B
2 1 C
2 2 B
```

I would like to pivot on column Z and have multi-index on columns X,Y, to create a truth table like so:

```
X Y A B C
---------
1 1 T T T
1 2 T F F
2 1 F T T
2 2 F T F
```

How do I do this in pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does it (almost):

```
pd.get_dummies(df,'Z').groupby(['X','Y']).max()
```

The following is closer to the exact output you asked for:

```
(pd.get_dummies(df,'Z')
 .groupby(['X','Y'])
 .max()
 .astype(bool)
 .applymap(lambda s: str(s)[0])
 .rename(columns=lambda v: v.replace('Z_','')))
```

Comment: And, `...astype(bool)`.

Comment: @Dov Grobgeld, A shorter syntax would be - `pd.get_dummies(df,'','').groupby(['X', 'Y']).max().replace({1:'T', 0:'F'})` and a `reset_index()` afterwards to get what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a value column of `Trues` and then use `pivot_table()`:

```
df["Value"] = True   
df.pivot_table("Value", ["X", "Y"], "Z", fill_value=False).reset_index()
```

[image]